# Appeal Hold on Question

Tags: discussion

I'd like to appeal https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205537/what-video-streaming-audio-streaming-is-used-in-microsoft-hololens

This question: [How to appeal a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57104/how-to-appeal-a-closed-question) says I should link it here and explain my case.

While my question may or may not be suited for Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange (it was being debated and from the massive amounts of downvotes I got I probably am incorrect). But the reason given for why the question was put on hold makes no sense (the use of electronic devices are off-topic). In no way am I asking how to use a HoloLens.

I feel like there was no good radio button option to put my question on hold so they chose some random one. If my question is going to be put on hold I want to it to be for a legitimate reason (ie computer engineering questions do not apply at electrical engineering stackexchange).

Please reopen, then if you must, put on hold for a legitimate reason.

UPDATE:
The reason this angers me is I posted very similar questions on other SE sites which I was upvoted for. Only this site destroyed my question. And it was not clear to me what the issue was. The next time I ask a question, it will probably be just as bad because I still don't understand what was wrong with that question other than it was NOT "electrical engineering" enough. But to myself I will continue to think, mob mentality makes it so much easier to downvote/close/call off-topic answers you can't answer than to take the time to find the answer.

Comment: You might want to read the comments people put under it there; it simply is offtopic. You are asking to speculate about how some product is built. The real problem here is that a question can not be closed for multiple reasons, as a lot of others would apply too.

Comment: @PlasmaHH as I stated in my question, that's fine. That's not what I'm angry about. I'm angry that it is on hold for something totally irrelevant to the question. No where do I ask how to use something

Comment: Just because the close reasons don't contain a specific close reason that fits to the question, doesn't mean its suddenly ontopic. The close reason fits that question better than the question fits the site. If you can only sleep better at night when you see a nice close reason there, you might want to write you a greasemonkey scrip that changes it whenever you visit it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The whole point of meta is to bring attention to inaccuracies in the site. If there is no good reason to close/put my question on hold, but it is truly off topic, that should be written into the site...

Comment: I sort of agree -- but that's not "appealing a hold", where you would be asking to have the hold removed.  No reason for that to happen.

Comment: @ScottSeidman If there is no current documentation on why my question is off-topic, I don't think it should be closed/on-hold. I think it should remain open until the real reason is added. That is completely unfair to a newbie like me. I did work to make sure my question fit in the bounds of the site bc I didn't want it to be downvoted/on-hold/closed. You and the others may have known it was off-topic from previous experience, but the reason in the "on hold" dialog is the only documentation that I have to go off of

Comment: The main point, IMO, is that reopening a question to then put it on hold again just for a little sentence is nonsense. There is good reason to put it on hold, so it's staying there. If a sufficiently high rep user comes along they can add a custom close reason, but will only do so if they expect this to add anything to the further interactions of the user. A short question asking opinion based questions on what might be and/or how would not have gotten that amount of effort from me either, being honest, as these are very clearly defined as off topic.

Comment: @Asmyldof There is no good reason that is well defined. where is it clearly defined?

Comment: Asking a question: "Here's some speculation about this, here's some patents -- What materials are used?" Is very clearly an opinion based, open ended discussion, and I __quote__: "please stick to those topics and **avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion.**" To then later add insult to injury by claiming "I've done my research by linking this bit of wild speculation". The reason we don't want those questions should be clear enough even without a help centre: Just look at the amount of "input" it has on reddit.

Comment: @Asmyldof How is what materials are used an opinion question? It's an exact answer based off of patents. But even that would have been better than "use of electronics"

Comment: @SethKitchen -  I'd consider it "Off-topic -- Other".  It was moderator closed, because it took a moderator to deal with the bounty sealing it open, but it doesn't take a rocket engineer to see that it would last about 5 minutes to get reclosed with 14 downvotes, no upvotes, a string of comments from users who would have voted it closed, and its own special metapost about how the bounty prevented closure.  Just because nobody can think of a SE to put it on, doesn't mean that it belongs here.  Maybe there's an Area51 proposal to consider.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I'd accept that as an answer

Comment: @SethKitchen can you try to generalize your question for this proposal?  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93532/hardware-hackers   I'm trying to create an alternative to EE that allows these questions and has a positive feedback attitude as to why a question is bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@SethKitchen - I'd consider it "Off-topic -- Other". It was moderator closed, because it took a moderator to deal with the bounty sealing it open, but it doesn't take a rocket engineer to see that it would last about 5 minutes to get reclosed with 14 downvotes, no upvotes, a string of comments from users who would have voted it closed, and its own special metapost about how the bounty prevented closure. Just because nobody can think of a SE to put it on, doesn't mean that it belongs here. Maybe there's an Area51 proposal to consider. – Scott Seidman 8 mins ago

Answer (score 6):

First, while you're certainly entitled to argue against one of your questions having gotten closed, it's a weenie thing to do.  The downvotes you are getting here may be as much for that as disagreement that the question should be re-opened.

Second, when you post something that is close-worthy, it gets closed.  It's quite unlikely the volunteers here that you irritated by posting a question that wasted their time reading it are going to go out of their way to explain exactly why it got closed.  Instead, they click on the nearest handy canned close reason and move on.  The effort/reward tradeoff just isn't worth spending time helping the guy who you just had to clean up after.  Of course, don't ignore the *screw you* attitude having to clean up someone else's mess fosters.

Now to your specific example.  I vaguely remember seeing this question originally, and I see I downvoted it.  The title asks how something is done in a product I never heard of before.  The fact that "HoloLens" isn't defined in the title is OK, but asking about what video and audio streaming is used already raises two red flags.  This doesn't sound like EE (what kind of streaming sounds like a software problem) and it also smells like asking for speculation (unless Microsoft published how they did this, how are we supposed to know without guessing?  If they did publish it, then why can't you read it like you're expecting us to do?).

Titles must be short, so that by itself wasn't a reason to close and downvote.  But the first sentence pretty much clinches it (*"How does Microsoft overlay holograms on a live feed?"*).  This HoloLens thing mentioned in the title is not defined but seems to be important to the question.  What holograms over what live feed?  These things weren't defined, and no, I'm not going to go searching the net to answer this question.  And again, overlaying holograms and live video or whatever doesn't sound like a electrical engineering problem.

I did read the next sentence (*"Are they constantly sending a cameras live stream to a computer and having the computer parse the live stream and render holograms from it?"*), which clinched it.  This is now clearly a high level software issue.  No circuits or even electronic technology are being asked about.  That and just expecting me to know what this Holothingy is without any introduction or explanation at all pissed me off.  I remember wondering whether you weren't Microsoft marketing trying to create awareness of a new product.

That's when I (probably, history seems to have been lost) voted to close, downvoted, and moved on.

### Added:

After reading the comment chain to your question here, I was reminded that this was the question that was locked open due a bounty.  Now I remember *that's* why I downvoted.  I was pissed that the bounty kept a question open that clearly didn't belong here, which it only tells you after you've gone thru the motions of voting to close.  Downvoting was my only way to vent any frustration with this question.  I remember I didn't originally intend to downvote, just close for what really should be obvious reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer. This makes sense and I think this should be added to the How to Ask or something like that. I was trying to get the electrical parts that make this sort of thing possible, but I can see how it is also a lot of software. Of course if I posted this on StackOverflow they'd say it was too much electronics

Comment: @Seth: You could try to ask about the electronics of how something is achieved, but 1 - You have to define it properly, and 2 - You have to be careful to avoid asking for speculation.